Given the transition matrix of a markov chain, can one find the fixed row vector thru mathematica?
Given the transition matrix of a markov chain, can one find the fixed row vector thru mathematica?
I have tried using the "Eigenvectors" function, but I don't understand what it's giving me so I'm not sure if it's the answer I'm looking for.
MatrixForm[
 as1 = {{2/3, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/3, 1/2, 1/6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/3, 
    1/2, 1/6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 1/2, 1/6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/3, 1/2, 
    1/6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2}}]

Eigenvectors[as1]


If the aim is to find the StationaryDistribution you can use DiscreteMarkovProcess
For example:
as1 = {{2/3, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/3, 1/2, 1/6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/3, 1/2,
     1/6, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 1/2, 1/6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/3, 1/2, 
    1/6}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2}};
dm = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, as1];
Graph[dm]
sd = StationaryDistribution[dm];
rf = RandomFunction[dm, {0, 1000}, 1000];
h = Histogram[rf["Paths"][[All, -1]][[All, 2]], Automatic, "PDF"];
Show[h, DiscretePlot[PDF[sd, x], {x, 1, 6}]]




{evals,evecs} = ToRadicals[Eigensystem[as1]]

evals[[1]]
evecs[[1]]


1
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

